# Sort List of Objects Based On Another Sorted List Object Positions In Java

Tags: java, sorting

I have two list objects like :

```
public class AttributeMaster {
    public String attribute_id;
    public String view_index;
    ...
}

List<AttributeMaster> attributes = new ArrayList<AttributeMaster>();

public class AttributeDetail {
    public String attribute_id;
    public String attribute_name;
    ...
}

List<AttributeDetail> attribute_detail = new ArrayList<AttributeDetail>();
```

Here, I need to sort `attribute_detail` list based on list `attributes`. List `attribute` is already sorted based on its `view_index` property.
I want to update second list based on index of `attribute_master` list.

If one one can help.

Comment: Your comment in the post is very confusing can you please be more clean and please use the tools that StackOverflow gives you, like add code between lines or words and please call the lists by the name of the variable and not by its content, rewrite this with a better explanation of what you want.

Comment: What `AttributeDetail` property is associated with the `AttributeMaster` property  `view_index`?

Comment: Its `attribute_id` which will connect both master and detail class of attribute.

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```
Collections.sort(attribute_detail, 
    Comparator.comparing(item -> attributes.indexOf(item)));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int start_index=0;
for(int i=0;i<attributes.size();i++) {

    for(int j=0;j<attribute_detail.size();j++) {
        if(attributes.get(i).getAttribute_id().equals(attribute_detail.get(j).getAttribute_id())){

            AttributeDetail temp=attribute_detail.get(start_index);
            attribute_detail.set(start_index, attribute_detail.get(j));
            attribute_detail.set(j,temp);
            start_index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Through index iterations, the code will check the object existence for both list using attribute_id. If the object present in both list, then it will sort the list of attribute_detail based on the index of attributes list.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your answer and add some context explaining how this code will solves the OP's question. Code-only answers are discouraged. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/25446137)